# Recommendations for a Hex Viewer Control for Windows.Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

I need ability to display content in Hex View, like this from WinHex

```
Offset      0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7   8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F
00000000   EF BB BF 0D 0A 4D 69 63  72 6F 73 6F 66 74 20 56   ï»¿..Microsoft V
00000010   69 73 75 61 6C 20 53 74  75 64 69 6F 20 53 6F 6C   isual Studio Sol
00000020   75 74 69 6F 6E 20 46 69  6C 65 2C 20 46 6F 72 6D   ution File, Form
00000030   61 74 20 56 65 72 73 69  6F 6E 20 31 30 2E 30 30   at Version 10.00
00000040   0D 0A 23 20 56 69 73 75  61 6C 20 53 74 75 64 69   ..# Visual Studi
00000050   6F 20 32 30 30 38 0D 0A  50 72 6F 6A 65 63 74 28   o 2008..Project(
00000060   22 7B 46 31 38 34 42 30  38 46 2D 43 38 31 43 2D   "{F184B08F-C81C-
00000070   34 35 46 36 2D 41 35 37  46 2D 35 41 42 44 39 39   45F6-A57F-5ABD99
```

Please recommend a control. Thank you.

Comment: You can try the hex viewer from this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/serialwizard/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have always used http://sourceforge.net/projects/hexbox/ which has a HexEditor control but can be also used in a read only mode.

Comment: This seems to require an external File as input.  Is there something that can take a Byte Array as input?  I'd rather not have to write out to a temp File just so it can read it back in.

Comment: Yes you can use the DynamicByteProvider which has a constructor backed by a byte array and set the ByteProvider property.

Answer (score 40):

There is a [ByteViewer Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.byteviewer.aspx) directly available in the .NET Framework. Here is how you can use it in a sample Winforms C# application (note: you need to reference the `System.Design` assembly):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ...
    ByteViewer bv = new ByteViewer();
    bv.SetFile(@"c:\windows\notepad.exe"); // or SetBytes
    Controls.Add(bv);
}
```

And here is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: You are, pretty much, the only person who mentions this on the entire interwebs. It's a fast, neat control. Not massively extensible, perhaps why it's not mentioned a lot. Still, thanks!

Comment: This is great, but i can't find it even after adding the `System.ComponentModel.Design` reference, i am using winforms in C#.

Comment: @Omarrrio - read the answer carefully, you need to add a Reference assembly (dll), not only a namespace

Comment: @SimonMourier ah sorry, i didn't know the difference, thank you.

Comment: @SimonMourier: This seems to require an external File as input.  Is there something that can take a Byte Array as input?  I'd rather not have to write out to a temp File just so it can read it back in.

Comment: @tom - read the answer carefully, you have a SetBytes method as well

Comment: Is there a way to make both panels simultaneously scroll-able without having to focus on the scroll bar?

Comment: How do you get his to work, this there a more comprehensive guide?

Comment: @Matt - just create a Winforms app, add a reference to System.Design assembly and copy paste my sample code. It should just work. What problem do you have?

Comment: Had no idea this even existed until now, thanks!

Comment: Awesome knowledge. This was pretty hidden!. However, is a viewer kinda useless, since it has no support for selecting and copying text. Also, the scrollbar is totally glitched: https://i.imgur.com/1tZOjAD.png. Now I understand why this component has the **ToolboxItem** and **DesignTimeVisible** class attributes set to **false** by default...

Comment: C# programmer since 1.1 and this is the first time I ever heard about it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Wpf Hexeditor is a powerful and fully customisable user control for editing file or stream as hexadecimal, decimal and binary.

You can use it very easily in Wpf or WinForm application. Download the code and test the Wpf (C#, VB.NET) and WinForm (C#) samples.

https://github.com/abbaye/WPFHexEditorControl

```
<!-- XAML -->
<Control:HexaEditor/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="NaN" Height="NaN"/>
<Control:HexaEditor Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
<Control:HexaEditor FileName={Binding FileNamePath} Width="Auto" Height="Auto"/>
```

[image: Image1]

Comment: You should better add more tutorials on this.

Comment: A lot of sample project is include

Answer (score 2):

You can try my **Simple HexView Control** project at

http://simplehexviewcontrol.codeplex.com/

Simple HexControl (HexView) is a classic Windows Forms control. It implements a hexadecimal view of bytes with grouping. It's blazing fast, renders only visible frame of a window and support of painting the individual groups of bytes without the total window redraw.

[image] 
[image]